# Extensible way to make class information accessible at runtime

Tags: c++, factory-pattern

I'm making a simple message-passing entity system. I have an Entity Descriptor table hooked into a factory for creating Entity subclasses at runtime, and I'd like to have it so they can be created by string:

```
EntityManager manager; //managers have all of the entity table information (See below)

//Counter is a sample class that inherits from Entity
Counter* counter = manager.makeEntity("Counter"); //the string doesn't have to match the class name.
```

Now, I know I can a simple switch statement, but I'd like the system to be extensible as well- that is, when I (or other users of my system) want to create a new Entity subclass, I don't have to go to the switch block and add it. Currently, I use Macros to create helper classes, which I instantiate statically, so that the constructor adds the entry to the Entity Table. These classes also initialize the entities and remove a lot of boilerplate from constructors.

```
//EHandle is a wrapper for Entity*. Currently std::shared_ptr<Entity>

class GenericDesc
{
public:
virtual ~GenericDesc() {}
    virtual EHandle makeEntity() const =0;
};

namespace Descriptor
{
    //Adds a descriptor to an internal map<string, GenericDesc*>
    void addEntityDescriptor(const std::string& type, GenericDesc& desc);
    EHandle newEntity(const std::string& type); //Factory method
}

//Add this to every entity class definition
#define DECLARE_ENTITY_CLASS(CLASS_NAME) \
    friend class CLASS_NAME##Descriptor;


//Use these after a class definition to add the entity class to the descriptor table
#define BEGIN_ENTITY_TYPE(ENTITY_NAME, CLASS_NAME, BASE_NAME) \
    BEGIN_ENTITY_TYPE_GUTS(ENTITY_NAME, CLASS_NAME) \
        BASE_NAME##Descriptor::prepareEntity(ent);

#define BEGIN_ENTITY_TYPE_BASELESS(ENTITY_NAME, CLASS_NAME) \
    BEGIN_ENTITY_TYPE_GUTS(ENTITY_NAME, CLASS_NAME) \
        ent->self = ent;

#define BEGIN_ENTITY_TYPE_GUTS(ENTITY_NAME, CLASS_NAME) \
class CLASS_NAME##Descriptor : public GenericDesc \
{ \
private: \
    typedef CLASS_NAME ClassName; \
public: \
    CLASS_NAME##Descriptor() \
    { \
        Descriptor::addEntityDescriptor(ENTITY_NAME, *this); \
    } \
    virtual ~CLASS_NAME##Descriptor() {} \
    virtual EHandle makeEntity() const\
    { \
        auto ent = std::shared_ptr<CLASS_NAME>(new CLASS_NAME); \
        prepareEntity(ent); \
        ent->type = ENTITY_NAME; \
        return ent; \
    } \
    static void prepareEntity(std::shared_ptr<ClassName> ent) \
    {

//These functions are caled between BEGIN_ENTITY_TYPE and END_ENTITY_TYPE
//ADD_ENTITY_INPUT binds a function to a string
#define ADD_ENTITY_INPUT(INPUT_NAME, INPUT_FUNC) \
        ent->addInput(INPUT_NAME, std::bind(&ClassName::INPUT_FUNC, ent, std::placeholders::_1));
//ADD_ENTITY_OUTPUT binds an Output object to a string
#define ADD_ENTITY_OUTPUT(OUTPUT_NAME, OUTPUT_OBJECT) \
        ent->addOutput(OUTPUT_NAME, ent->OUTPUT_OBJECT);

#define END_ENTITY_TYPE(CLASS_NAME) \
    } \
}; \
static CLASS_NAME##Descriptor CLASS_NAME##Desc; //TODO: find a way to fix the multiple-static-allocation issue
```

The idea is that you create a BEGIN_ENTITY_TYPE(...) END_ENTITY_TYPE(...) Clause, with ADD_ENTITY_x bits in the middle. My question is whether there is a less macro-y way to do this, that still minimizes boilerplate and doesn't require modifying any files outside of the one that defines the Entity subclass. A template class could work, but I don't know how I would do the ADD_ENTITY_INPUT/OUTPUT stuff with a template class.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be entirely what you're after, but consider something like:

```
class Factory
{
public:
    virtual void InitialiseFactory() = 0;
    Entity* CreateEntity( string type )
    {
        // (obviously, you must handle the string not being found.)
        return m_MapEntities[ type ]->Clone();
    }
};

class MyFactory : public Factory
{
public:
    void InitialiseFactory()
    {
        m_MapEntities["typea"] = new MyEntity();
    } 
};
```

The idea here is that the lookup is concretised in the base class which can remain unchanged, but the specifics of which Entities are provided is in the implementation of the derived class.

Another way would be for a static method in each Entity making a call to the factory to be added, but that method still needs to be called from somewhere.